# Why 25 hours in a day? PHP/Date

Tags: php, laravel, datetime

Example Laravel/Carbon:

```
    $from = Carbon::parse('2009-10-25 00:00:00');
    $to = Carbon::parse('2009-10-26 00:00:00');
    dd($from->diffInHours($to)); // echo 25
```

Difference in hours equal 25 hours. Why?

Comment: Checkout this https://github.com/briannesbitt/Carbon/issues/88

Comment: Did the Daylight Saving Time end in 2009 in your timezone between October 16 and October 25?

Comment: perhaps, but this case return 48 instead of 49.  $from = Carbon::parse('2009-10-25 00:00:00');
    $to = Carbon::parse('2009-10-26 23:59:59');
    dd($from->diffInHours($to)); // echo 48

Comment: Carbon [docs](http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-difference) for differnce state that "All values are truncated and not rounded."

Answer (score 0):

In 2009, Daylight Saving ended October 25, hence the difference is really 25 hours between 2009-10-25 00:00:00 and 2009-10-26 00:00:00, at least for my timezone (MEZ) as the dates get parsed in the default timezone.

You can set the timezone to UTC to overcome the issue:

```
$from = \Carbon\Carbon::parse('2009-10-25 00:00:00 UTC');
$to = \Carbon\Carbon::parse('2009-10-26 00:00:00 UTC');
dd($from->diffInHours($to)); // echo 24
```